# Event click a item on android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new student on xamarin android. so I don't know how to create a event click on that.

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_home"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_48dp"
      android:title="Home" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_genre"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_toc_black_48dp"
      android:title="Genres" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_audio"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_input_antenna_black_48dp"
      android:title="Audio" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_download"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_get_app_black_48dp"
      android:title="Download" />
  </group>
  <item android:title="Account">
   <menu>
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
   <item 
     android:id="@+id/nav_about"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_open_black_48dp"
     android:title="About"/>
     <item 
     android:id="@+id/nav_signout"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_48dp"
     android:title="Sign out"/>
  </group>
    
   </menu>
  </item>
 
</menu>
```

```html
<!-- your content layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <frameLayout
             android:id:="@+id/frameContainer"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"

            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to when click that item 1 -> fragmenthome(there only listview)

I want to when click that item 2 -> fragmentgenres(there only listview)

They all be showing up in  frameContainer.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2):

This is how to handle click events and load fragments accordingly.

```
HomeFragment homFragment;
GenresFragment genresFragment;
int currentFragmentId=Resource.Id.nav_home;
```

Above declarations are to be made global in the Activity.

```
var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView> (Resource.Id.nav_view);
navigationView.NavigationItemSelected+= NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
CreateFragments ();
LoadInditialFragment ();
```

Add the above snippets in OnCreate.

```
void CreateFragments()
    {
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment ();
        genresFragment = new GenresFragment ();
    }

void LoadInditialFragment()
    {
        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        transaction.Add (Resource.Id.frameContainer, genresFragment).Hide(genresFragment);
        transaction.Add (Resource.Id.frameContainer, homeFragment);
        transaction.Commit ();
    }

void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MenuItem.ItemId != currentFragmentId)
            SwitchFragment (e.MenuItem.ItemId);

        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers ();
    }

void SwitchFragment(int FragmentId)
    {
        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();


            switch (currentFragmentId) 
            {
            case Resource.Id.nav_home:
                transaction.Hide (homeFragment).Commit ();
                break;
            case Resource.Id.nav_genre:
                transaction.Hide (genresFragment).Commit ();
                break;
            }
        transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        switch (FragmentId) 
        {
        case Resource.Id.nav_home:
            transaction.Show (homeFragment);
            transaction.Commit ();
            break;
        case Resource.Id.nav_genre:
            transaction.Show (genresFragment);
            transaction.Commit ();
            break;
        }

        currentFragmentId = FragmentId;
    }
```

In the Create Fragment Method All Fragments are instantiated initially and attached to the Fragment. Then all fragments except the fragment to be shown are hidden. Then as the user clicks on an item in NavigationView the current fragment is hidden and the fragment corresponding to the menu item is shown. In this approach each fragment will not be created each time user switches menu. Thus pages will load faster.

Comment: nav_home is id  of listview that it is in homegragment?

Comment: nav_home is the Id of the MenuItem in NavigationMenu which corresponds to HomeFragment

Comment: If I want to give a parameter to homeFragment. How to do that?

Comment: You want to give parameter only once initially or every time you navigate to the fragment ?

Comment: Defin a method that accepts that parameter in HomeFragment. Then, invoke that method in SwitchFragment just before this line transaction.Show (homeFragment);

Comment: FragmentId Unknown identifier: FragmentId